# QT and C#: Can I mix them for mobile development?

Tags: c#, qt, mobile

I heard, c#.net and QT can be mixed for mobile development. I shall like to share of your experience with the same.

Basically, we have c#.Net background and wish to reuse the skill/knowledge of these for expanding products into mobile platform. We have seen J2ME. But it needs specific skill/resource development. We shall prefer .Net for this. But Windows mobile is not having too much of footprint.

Shall like to have your inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two processes and communicate via say socket/shared memory. So it's possible to merge different codebase and deploy.

However if you are looking to target app stores etc. I suggest you stick to one language only. If you intend to make UI using QT then you would end up teaching yourself Qt Designer, SIGNAL SLOT Mechanism etc. I guess from there it's not a huge learning curve to make the entire app in Qt/C++.

Windows on Mobile has a very small footprint. If you want you app to target all app stores or more than you should try HTML5

Comment: My target is not app stores. It is for some Field force automation and mainly GIS based app. So handset models and related things are in my control to a great extent.

Comment: Got your point. Take a look at Qt Quick and Mobility API of Qt, As for .Net I just think market share is negligible ... if you already have skills in it along with type handset being in your control I think you are best judge.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only interested in using QML (Qt Quick) for UI and writing the backend in .NET (Mono) it is also possible to utilize the Qt Metaobject System for binding C# (or any other IL) classes to QML.
We implemented this and it works really well.

Comment: Do you have an example of this?

Comment: Not in public domain, sorry. We implemented this as a prototype for a client. But you can look at the python bindings for qml, they work the same way.